# JSON Schema - if then statement is always evaluated even when "if" isn't true

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a JSON Schema, in the schema - when the property `type` is equal to `menu`, then the property `default` should be an integer or a string called "default". The problem is, the schema is throwing a warning / error that the `default` property should be an integer, even when `type` is not "menu".

(There are properties in the JSON named "type" and "default", not to be confused with the JSON schema type & default keys).

The Schema cut down to the relevant properties:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "title": "HubSpot Module",
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The type of field, see [field types](https://developers.hubspot.com/en/docs/cms/building-blocks/module-theme-fields#field-types) for documentation on all field types."
        },
        "default": {
          "type": ["string", "integer", "array", "boolean", "null", "number", "object"],
          "description": "Default value for the field.",
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "const": "menu"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                  "default"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "description": "The menu ID for the menu. The default value of null, defaults to the default menu under navigation.",
            "default": "null"
          },
          "else": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "type": ["string", "integer", "array", "boolean", "null", "number", "object"]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "label",
        "type"
      ]
    }
  }
```

It works when those conditions are met, e.g.

```json
[
  {
    "label": "Primary menu field",
    "name": "primary_menu_field",
    "type": "menu",
    "default": 123
  }
]

[
  {
    "label": "Primary menu field",
    "name": "primary_menu_field",
    "type": "menu",
    "default": "default"
  }
]
```

neither of these throw warnings. However the following throws the warning: `Incorrect type. Expected "integer".`

```json
[
  {
    "name": "boolean_field",
    "label": "Boolean field",
    "required": false,
    "locked": false,
    "type": "boolean",
    "inline_help_text": "",
    "help_text": "",
    "default": false 
  }
]
```

Despite the `type` property not being named "menu". Hovering over the "default" property VSCode does give me the definition I have for it.

It seems like the `if` statement is always being evaluated as true - when it should only be evaluated if the value of property `type` is `menu`, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` isn't working as expected because it's in the wrong place and it's insufficiently constrained. You have the `if` in the "default" property schema which means the `if` schema will apply to the value of the "default" property. So, if "default" is `123`, then the `if` schema,

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "type": { "const": "menu" }
  }
}
```

will be evaluated against `123`. Since `123` is a number, the `properties` keyword is ignored and the schema will pass validation and the `then` schema will apply. This is what I meant by `if` being under constrained. When using `if` you need to check for missing data or data of the wrong type.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": { "const": "menu" }
  },
  "required": ["type"]
}
```

Now you'll get an error message when validating `123` against this schema and hopefully figure out that your `if`/`then` is in the wrong place. The `if` needs to apply to the object, you need to move it up to that level in the schema. That will make your `if` evaluated as expected. Don't forget to update the `then` as well since you moved the schema. I also needs to be defined at the object level rather than the property level.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",

  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "type": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "required": ["name", "label", "type"],

    "if": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": { "const": "menu" }
      },
      "required": ["type"]
    },
    "then": {
      "properties": {
        "default": {
          "anyOf": [
            { "type": "integer" },
            { "const": "default" }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if`/`then`/`else` is under the `default` property, so it's looking for an object under `default`, rather than one level up where you want it.

Also, the `properties` check in the `if` condition will always be true if the property doesn't actually exist, so to ensure it does, you can add a `"required": <propertyname>` alongside it.

(Orthogonally, your `type` check doesn't really do anything since you include all valid types in the list. You might as well just leave it out to indicate "this can be any type".)